# Как установить target избежав lookAt() в OrbitControls?

Tags: three.js

Стоит задача сделать камеру как в Autodesk Revit, а именно, при выборе элемента в фокус мы устанавливаем его позицию как центр вращения камеры. Всё отлично, за исключением того, что при

```js
controls.target.set(focusObject.position.x, focusObject.position.y, focusObject.position.z);
```

камера начинает смотреть в позицию объекта. Вообще это ведь OrbitControls, а значит так оно и должно быть, но мне нужно что-бы камера оставалась на том же месте, смотрела в ту же позицию куда и смотрела до момента выбора объекта, но вращалась вокруг выбранного в фокус объекта, т.е. нужно сделать камеру независимой от цента вращения. Подскажите, может-быть вы встречали controls с таким функционалом, или, возможно, кастомизировали OrbitControls? Если да, то как?

Comment: можете гифку добавить? я кажется понимаю о чем Вы но не уверен полностью